# Free SMTP Server for Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, smtp, mailing-lists

i am looking to have an SMTP server, for Windows 2003, that:

- is easily configurable
- is free
- allows me to send newsletters to hundreds of people at a time
- has a good statistics module (bounces, hard bounces, etc.)
- doesn't take a big toll on the server's processing

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the Windows version of [OpenEmm](http://www.openemm.org/), although I have to say that I have only used the Linux version - which works very well.

Comment: thanx, i'm going to try it out. seems perfect